# Remove out label from a Flask Form

Tags: html, css, flask

I have been trying to style my form, created using Flask and this is a particular issue I'm facing.
I'm unable to find a way to remove the "No file chosen" field from the picture field, and I can not find a method to style the upload button, like I usually can using CSS. I am also using bootstrap in my file.

This is how the form field looks like upon hovering:

[image: This is how my image looks like upon hovering]

I want only the "Choose file" button to be visible upon hovering on the image, and I would like to style it like a bootstrap button.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: as  I know you can't style it. Other pages may hide this button and display fake button with JavaScript code which clicks hidden `Choose File` when you click fake button.

Comment: @furas Yes I was considering this option too. Can you expand this idea into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you can't style it.

Some pages simply hide it and use own button with JavaScript code to click file input.

When you click this button then it runs JavaScript code which runs `click()` on `file input`.

More complex code can even get filename with `drag'a'drop` and send this name to `file input`.

---

Minimal working example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.files['image'])
        print(request.files.getlist('image'))

    return render_template_string('''
<style>
input[type="file"] {
   display: none;
}
button {
    border: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
button[name="select"] {
    background-color: lime;
}
button[name="button"] {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" id="file_input" style="display:None"/></br>
<button type="button" name="select" value="send" onclick="open_selection();">SELECT IMAGE</button>
<button type="submit" name="button" value="send">SEND</button>
</form>

<script>
var file_input = document.getElementById("file_input");

function open_selection() {
    file_input.click();
}
</script>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

[image]

---